# python3 function to check if parameter is a power of 2 with a while loop and without using math function

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Learning about functions in python3.  A course question was to define a function using a while loop (and without using the math function) that determines if a parameter is a power of 2.  If it is, return True.  If it is not, return False.  Here is the starting code:

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
  # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  while n % 2 == 0:
    n = n / 2
  # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
  if n == 1:
    return True
  return False
  

print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

I can find examples with loops (other than while) and when using the math function, but am at a loss without
either of those options.

Comment: you should add an extra condition in loop (or before) for the special cases 0 and 1, the rest code is fine

Answer (score 2):

`n=0` is a special case since `0 % 0 == 0`. That's why you had an infinite loop.

You can also simplify your `return` statement by using `return n == 1`

The function:

```
def is_power_of_two(n): 
    if n  == 0: 
        return False 

    while n % 2 == 0: 
        n = n / 2 

    return n == 1
```

tests:

```
print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False 
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True 
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True 
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False                                                   
print(is_power_of_two(8.1)) # Should be False
```

output:

```
False
True
True
False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
  # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  # special cases: 0, because 0 % 2 = 0
  # you can either use the n > 0 extra test below
  # if n == 0: return False # or an explicit test for zero
  while (n > 0) and (n % 2 == 0): n = n / 2
  # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
  return n == 1
```

[Online example](https://repl.it/repls/FlickeringFirsthandLogin#main.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break` to exit the infinite loop:

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
  # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  while n % 2 == 0:
    if(n==0): 
      break
    n = n / 2
  # If after dividing by 2 the number is 1, it's a power of two
  if n == 1:
    return True
  return False
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.